# Access keepass base in google drive

Tags: google-drive, keepassxc

I have keepass database on google drive. Is it possible to bind it to keepassxc (ver 2.5.4) on ubuntu (now i updated to focal). I can reach google drive with nautilus, but i do not see it from Keepass when try to open base.

Comment: Either use the OPEN menu in KP and find the DB file, or double-click on the DB file, and when it asks which application to open it with, chose KP.

Comment: Thank you very much double click worked (silly me). The problem was that in KP in OPEN menu were no google drive link - that confused me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Double clicking the file will open it, but it's not possible to save(write) the file.